# Filter Table with CSS and JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a dynamic table that I am displaying in the front end like this:

```
 <table id ="tblRE">
    <tr class="row">
      <th ng-repeat="column in cols_re">{{column}}</th>
    </tr>
       
    <tr ng-repeat="row in data['dict_re']">
      <td ng-repeat="column in cols_re">{{row[column]}}</td>
    </tr>  
  </table>
```

I want to put a filter on one of the columns named **OUT**(my 2nd column from the table).

If I would have a fix column name I would do like this:

```
<tr class="row">
     <td class="head" ng-click="sortData='OUT';sortOrder=!sortOrder"> OUT</td>
</tr>

<tr ng-repeat="item in data.table_df| orderBy:sortData:sortOrder | filter:filter ">
    <td>{{ item.OUT}}</td>
</tr>
```

Is there an option on how I can put the filter with my initial option?

I also tried to add a search button which kind of works only for the first column. I want to be able to filter also on the second column.

The code for the search button:

js:

```
function searchre() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("tblRE");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
}
```

and in HTML:

```
<input class="myInput" type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="searchre()" placeholder="Search.." title="Type in a name">
```

Any idea on how I can filter on the first and 2nd column?

Comment: none of the above html snippets of the tables do not have a second column